# Android Studio umake fail: no license

Tags: android-studio, license, ubuntu-make

With v. 15.10, I follow the umake method:sudo apt install ubuntu-make; umake android; Choose installation path: /home/.... ,; Then:
  "ERROR: We were expecting to find a license on the download page, we didn't."
My question: what are they talking about?

Answer (score 1):

When you run umake, it checks the Android Studio website for license text, which it then prompts you to accept. It looks like the website was changed, probably when Android Studio 2.0 was released recently, so the installer can't find the license in the expected location. You can get around this by disabling the license check: `umake android android-studio --accept-license`.

There's [a bug for this issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/288) on the umake GitHub project, and it's apparently been fixed. The [readme](https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make) suggests using the Ubuntu Make PPA rather than the version in the Ubuntu repository to ensure that you're always using the latest version.

Comment: thanks for the `umake` tip to use  `--accept-license` -- RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Android studio and the sdk changed the download pages significantly.
They’ve been fixed in master, and will be working again in the next release.

If you need you can clone the repository and install from that.
It’s less than ideal, but if it can help you for the time being.

```
git clone https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make
cd ubuntu-make
bin/umake android
```

Ref:
https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/302